# Expand months on click of year

Tags: jquery

How can I expand (and toggle) `archiveMenuMonths` on click of the year link?

```
<div class="archiveMenu">
    <ul class="archiveMenuYear">
        <li class="year">
            <a href="#">2016</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="archiveMenuMonths">
        <li class="month">
            <a href="#">July</a>
        </li>
        <li class="month">
            <a href="#">June</a>
        </li>
        <li class="month">
            <a href="#">May</a>
        </li>
        <li class="month">
            <a href="#">March</a>
        </li>
        <li class="month">
            <a href="#">February</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

I have `archiveMenuMonths` set to `display:none;`.

At the moment this doesn't seem to fire:

```
$(function() {
   $('.year a').click(function() {
       $(this).next('.archiveMenuMonths').show();
       return false;
   });        
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It fires, your selector to show the element is wrong tho. `archiveMenuMonths` is not the next element relative to the clicked anchor - you need to go up to the `ul`, then to the next `ul`

```
$(this).closest("ul.archiveMenuYear").next('.archiveMenuMonths').toggle();
```